# Should I put guard clauses in ASP.NET Core controllers?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

From the perspective of unit testing, general development and code readability should I be putting guard clauses to check for null parameters injected to controllers?

Or should I rely on ASP.NET Core framework that it will not pass null or invalid parameters if everything is properly configured (eg. DI Container, model binding and other configurations)?

Here is the sample controller without guard clauses:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly string _message;

    public HomeController(IRepository repository, IMapper mapper, string message)
    {
        _liveEventsRepository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _message = message;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSomeData([FromQuery]QueryParameters parameters)
    {
        var result = _repository.GetData(parameters);
        var items = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyItemDto>>(result.MyItems);
        return Ok(new
        {
            items,
            result.TotalItemsCount
        });
    }
}
```

If I add guard clauses like following:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly string _message;

    public HomeController(IRepository repository, IMapper mapper, string message)
    {
        if (repository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        if (mapper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mapper");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
            throw new ArgumentException("text");

        _liveEventsRepository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _message = message;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSomeData([FromQuery]QueryParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            throw ArgumentNullException("parameters");

        var result = _repository.GetData(parameters);
        var items = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyItemDto>>(result.MyItems);
        return Ok(new
        {
            items,
            result.TotalItemsCount
        });
    }
}
```

does this add any value to my code base? Or should I completely skip guard clauses in ASP.NET Core controllers considering the underlying framework infrastructure and assuming everything is properly set?

Also from the perspective of unit testing, should I be testing controller constructor and actions by passing null/invalid parameters or is that unneeded overhead?

Comment: There's a huge difference in guarding against DI-provided services in a constructor and user-provided values in an Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to this is going to be opinionated. There is no necessarily right or wrong answer here. You can certainly trust that the controller will be injected with any dependencies it requires. If it can't, an exception will be thrown regardless.

However, I still tend to use guards for two reasons. First, I'm a strong proponent of consistency. If you start making distinctions that this thing needs guards but this other thing doesn't, then inevitably, you won't always think to add guards, and will leave them out in places they should actually be. If you just add guards all the time, then your behavior is consistent and you never miss anything.

Second, when unit testing, you will be responsible for filling in the dependencies (to some extent or another), so the guard clauses serve as a sanity check of your test code. If you forget to satisfy a certain dependency, you'll know exactly why the code is failing, instead of some random error caused later in the code once that dependency is actually attempted to be used.

In short, it's one of those cost-benefit conclusions. How much effort does it take to add the guard clauses? They certainly won't hurt anything being there if they aren't actually needed, but what benefit do they provide by being there? Well, consistency and sanity checks, which are actually pretty valuable things, when it comes to tracking down bugs and just maintaining code in general.

For what it's worth, you should really use throw expressions, as it's cleaner and easier, which just makes the decision to do it that much easier:

```
_liveEventsRepository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
_mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
_message = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) ? message : throw new ArgumentException("Value must not be null or whitespace.", nameof(message));
```